# checkbox toggle doesn't work correctly react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this checkbox example

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    check: true,
    };}

checkBoxtTest(){
this.setState(
 {check:!this.state.check})}
```

> on return

```
 <CheckBox
    value={this.state.check} onChangee={()=>this.checkBoxtTest()}
/>
```

when i press again in checkbox the value doesn't change

Comment: this.setState((prevState) => ({check: !prevState.check})) .. make the function as arrow function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, ListItem, CheckBox, Text, Body } from 'native-base';
export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: true
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <ListItem>
                        <CheckBox
                            checked={this.state.checked}
                            onPress={() => this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})}
                        />
                        <Body>
                        <Text>Finish list Screen</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </ListItem>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i used  native-base instead of react-native ,, its work ! thank you

Answer (score 1):

you are having a typo 'onChange'

```
<CheckBox
    value={this.state.check} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxtTest()}
/>
```

If you are using state for changing state follow this way

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({check: !prevState.check}))
```

You can use arrow function instead of normal function

```
checkBoxtTest = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({check: !prevState.check}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,change it to `onChange`.And your `checkBoxTest` should be bind in the `constructor` as it is recommended as best practice.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    check: true,
    };
    this.checkBoxtTest = this.checkBoxtTest.bind(this);
}

checkBoxtTest(){
  this.setState({
    check : !this.state.check
  })
}

<CheckBox value={this.state.check} onChange={this.checkBoxtTest()} />
```

Comment: Using this.state.check for changing state itself might create some issues if your code become complex so we must always use previous state provided by setState function

Comment: Shubham Agarwal Bhewanewala  thats help me thank you